# How would I make a looping text marquee that is clipped to a path?

Tags: html, css, svg, marquee, svg-animate

i'm still quite inexperienced with coding in general, but what I'm trying to do is to make an infinite marquee of text that is clipped to an svg path

I tried looking around and having a go. But I can't seem to get the text to appear to see if my loop is even working

This is where i'm currently at.

```
<svg width="500" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path id="textPathCurve" d="M1.02632 392.868L1.02612 207.995C1.02612 115.501 73.223 0.986328 209.439 0.986328C345.655 0.986328 422.088 119.564 422.088 207.995L419.299 390.079C419.299 473.617 346.07 590.261 212.692 590.261C66.9114 590.261 1.02632 460.671 1.02632 392.868Z" fill="none" />

  <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18" fill="black">
    <textPath href="#textPathCurve" startOffset="100%">
      JOIN THE MOVEMENT > JOIN THE MOVEMENT > JOIN THE MOVEMENT >
    </textPath>
  </text>

  <style>
    @keyframes moveText {
      to {
        startOffset: -100%;
      }
    }

    textPath {
      animation: moveText 5s linear infinite;
    }
  </style>
</svg>
```

my SVG is showing, however no text is appearing at all to see if the loop is working.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is partially hidden because its outside the `viewbox` of the SVG so you need to adjust that.

Secondly, `startOffset` is not a CSS property and so cannot be animated with keyframe animation.

You need to place the `animation` inside the textpath like so.

```
   <textPath href="#textPathCurve" startOffset="0%">
      JOIN THE MOVEMENT > JOIN THE MOVEMENT > JOIN THE MOVEMENT >
       <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-100%" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </textPath>
```

```css
svg {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-50 -50 550 650" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path id="textPathCurve" d="M1.02632 392.868L1.02612 207.995C1.02612 115.501 73.223 0.986328 209.439 0.986328C345.655 0.986328 422.088 119.564 422.088 207.995L419.299 390.079C419.299 473.617 346.07 590.261 212.692 590.261C66.9114 590.261 1.02632 460.671 1.02632 392.868Z" fill="none" />

  <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18" fill="black">
    <textPath href="#textPathCurve" startOffset="0%">
      JOIN THE MOVEMENT > JOIN THE MOVEMENT > JOIN THE MOVEMENT >
       <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-100%" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```